# Cannot save property group to product in django-lfs

Tags: django, e-commerce

I already create properties and add them to property group.Then I assign to my new product.But django show me

```
TypeError at /manage/update-product-properties/1
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'
```

Comment: hmm problem gone with django version 1.1.1 and 1.1.2  not 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, as you point out in your comment to your OP, the problem went away by using a different version of Django. `using` is part of the machinery for multi-database support in Django 1.2